# Reactjs SPA - Pressing IOS Safari back button updates the url but not the component view

Tags: reactjs

We have a reactjs SPA application where we want to navigate back and forth using browser back button/swipe the screen, if on Mac.

when a user clicks on a link from home page, they will be navigated to a detail page and the url looks like **https://example.com/pdetail?prdt=Computer**

On detail page, User has an ability to search, and when the user searches(Say Stationery), we update the url and push the url to history and the the detail page component is updated with the searched data.Like

**https://example.com/pdetail?prdt=Stationery**

```
 filterSearch(searchval) {
  //search related code to set variables
  let newUrl = setParams(searchval, 'prdt')
  this.props.history.push(`?${newUrl}`);
// dispatch an api call to get data
}

 export function setParams(query = "", param) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  searchParams.set(param, query.trim());
  return searchParams.toString();
}
```

Now when the user browse back using the browser back button, we expect it to go the previous data(https://example.com/pdetail?prdt=Computer) from (https://example.com/pdetail?prdt=Stationery) and Vice Versa as we move back and forth. It is working fine in chrome and IE.

But in Safari, as the user presses back button, url is changing in the browser but the component view is not.

as we navigate back, I noticed that it did not go to ComponentDidMount as we go to the same page. But it goes ComponentDidUpdate so I added my code in there.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    window.onpopstate  = (e) => {

        if(this.props.history.action == 'POP')
        {
            e.preventDefault(); 

            const search = window.location.search; 

            const params = new URLSearchParams(search);

            if(params.has('prdt') === true)
            {
                 const selectedprdt = params.get('prdt');

                 this.props.fetchDetails('FETCH_PRDT_DETAILS' , selectedprdt);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Let me know how can get this back forth page navigation with consistent url and data in Safari.
It is working fine in IE and chrome.

**EDIT:**

I have edited my code to add an eventListener in componentDidMount and UI is working in Safari. But when I see in the logs, I noticed the event runs multiple times not just once, which is very inefficient as we are making server calls.

```
componentDidMount()
{

    const selectedprdt = getParams(window.location, 'prdt');
    if(selectedprdt !== '')
    {    
        this.props.fetchDetails('FETCH_PRDT_DETAILS' , selectedprdt);
    }


   window.addEventListener('popstate', this.handleBackButton)
}

handleBackButton = (e) =>
{

    if(this.props.history.action == 'POP')
    {


        const search = window.location.search; 

        const params = new URLSearchParams(search);

        if(params.has('prdt') === true)
        {
             const selectedMarket = params.get('prdt');

             this.props.fetchDetails('FETCH_PRDT_DETAILS' , selectedprdt);
        }


        e.preventDefault(); 

    }

}
```

Please let me know how to stop eventListener to executing the calls multiple times.

Thanks,

Comment: You should try using [`react-router`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: @sudo97, can you please elaborate your answer. We are using react-router-dom

Comment: what version of `react-router` are you using

Comment: AFAIK if you `BrowserRouter` from the latest `react-router` it comes with the functionality of pressing the back button out of the box. They have an example [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the same listener on component Unmount.

```
componentWillUnMount() 
{ 
  window.removeEventListener('popstate', this.handleBackButton) 
}
```